# Manifest XML parsing using DocumentBuilder - failing to get some node attributes

Tags: java, android, xml

To be more specific, I have written an xml parser to look through a manifest file for an Android application as part of a lint inspection; This code was previously working, and began failing after updating to Android Studio 3.0, though I can't see any way why this would cause the issue.

Here is the `application` node of my manifest:

```
<application
   android:name=".App"
   android:allowBackup="false"
   android:icon="@drawable/app"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:supportsRtl="false"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
   tools:replace="android:allowBackup">
```

When attempting to iterate over the attributes for the `application` node in my manifest, I've used the following snippet of code:

```
// the variable `f` is my manifest file; I've confirmed it is the correct file
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
org.w3c.dom.Document manifest = builder.parse(f);

// in practice this list only ever has 1 element
NodeList applicationList = manifest.getElementsByTagName("application");

if (applicationList.getLength() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < applicationList.getLength(); i++) {
        org.w3c.dom.Node application = applicationList.item(i);
        NamedNodeMap attributes = application.getAttributes();
        // checking the size of `attributes` here gives 3
        // but my application node has 7 attributes
        for (int j = 0; j < attributes.getLength(); j++) {
            // I examine the attributes here
        }
    }
}
```

One would expect if the `attributes` items names were listed out, it would yield `android:name`, `android:allowBackup`, `android:icon`, `android:label`, `android:supportsRtl`, `android:theme`, and `tools:replace`; however, only 3 attributes are reported: `android:allowBackup`, `android:label`, and `android:supportsRtl`

No exceptions are thrown by the parser, but now my lint inspection is failing because it detects missing attributes that are needed for the check to pass.  In the short term I can obviously just remove the inspection, but I'm completely at a loss as to why it would detect some attributes and ignore others.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I ran your code and got android:allowBackup="false"
android:icon="@drawable/app"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:name=".App"
android:supportsRtl="false"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
tools:replace="android:allowBackup"

Comment: Out of curiosity, what tool are you using to run the code?

Comment: I ran it from Eclipse